# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I don't know how to solve this problem... Please, help me with this, I'm just beginner

```
  const onSubmit = async (e) => { //Here I submit my form
    e.preventDefault();
    const nickname = e.target.nickname.value;
    if (!nickname || !fileUrl) {
      return;
    }
    await db.collection("request").doc(playerID).set({
      nickname: nickname,
      image: fileUrl,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRequest = async () => {
      const requestCollection = await db.collection("request").get();
      setRequest(
        requestCollection.docs.map((doc) => {
          return doc.data();
        })
      );
    };
    fetchRequest();
  }, []);
```

Return:

```
  return (
    <Panel id={id}>
      <Div>
          <FormLayout>
             <Input maxLength="16" top="Введите ваш никнейм" nickname={nickname} onChange={(e) => setNickname(e.target.value)} placeholder="Dit"/>
             <Input  maxLength="8" top="Введите ваш игровой ID" playerID={playerID} onChange={(e) => setPlayerID(e.target.value)} type="tel" placeholder="675"/>
             <Select  top="Категория" value={category} onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)} placeholder="Выберите категорию скина">
               <option value="Обычные скины">Обычные скины</option>
               <option value="Питомцы">Питомцы</option>
               <option value="Частицы">Частицы</option>
             </Select>
             <File type='file' top="Загрузите ваше фото" onChange={onFileChange} before={<Icon24Camera />} controlSize="l">
          Открыть галерею
        </File>
             <Button mode="commerce" size="xl" onClick={(e) => {onSubmit(); onGoHome();}} data-to="home" >Отправить</Button>
              </FormLayout>
              <ul>
        {request.map((playerID) => {
          return (
            <li key={playerID.nickname}>
              <img width="100" height="100" src={playerID.image} alt={playerID.nickname} />
              <p>{playerID.nickname}</p>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
  </Div>
    </Panel>
  );
}
```

I'll be so glad if someone will teach me... I use Firebase Cloud Firestore for Database and storage.
I was trying to find an answer but i couldn't

Comment: Tell me if you need more code or explanations

Comment: Add the `e` parameter to your onSubmit call: `onClick={(e) => {onSubmit(e) ...`

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Now i got this error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```
const nickname = e.target.nickname.value;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what default are you trying to prevent anyway?..   Your button is just a normal button, it's not of type submit, so the only thing it's going to do is what you put in your onClick.

Comment: I don't know, i just took this at tutor. Should i delete this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make React event handlers `async`. React uses a synthetic (custom) event system, and event instances may be lost before your handler has the chance to run.

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling

Solution: remove the `async` from `onSubmit`, extract the async code into an new function (which may be async):

```js
const handleSubmit = async (nickname) => {
    if (!nickname || !fileUrl) {
      return;
    }
    await db.collection("request").doc(playerID).set({
      nickname: nickname,
      image: fileUrl,
    });
}

const onSubmit = async (e) => { //Here I submit my form
    e.preventDefault();
    const nickname = e.target.nickname.value;
    this.handleSubmit(nickname);
  };
```

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. Short update: "You can't make React event handlers async" is not 100% incorrect. You can make them async, but then cannot access the event object (as experienced).